# How do you reference value of column from a different column attributes page in Oracle Apex?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am in a report page in APEX. I went to the report attributes page and inside that are columns which each have their own column attributes.  I needed to know how to use the value of one column while I am in a separate column's attribute page. With the picture attached, I try to do above using #COLUMNNAME# to get the value, but the correct value is not being used. You use hashtags to reference column values in the column formatting section. [image: Where I am trying to use column value.]

Comment: The value I use is disabled="true" or null, so I can restrict editing which is set based on another column value. And usually if I just have disabled="true" where the #EDITABLE# is in the picture, the functionality works. But when I try to use the column value, it doesn't. And the editable column is being set correctly, I checked the values. Thanks for any ideas! @Typo

Comment: You could probably use a dynamic action for this instead.

Comment: Show me HTML-code of the page (not whole page, but only one row of the report) when you use #EDITABLE#.

Comment: Stop. I think it doesn't work. I have tried in my APEX 4.2 - this method doesn't work. I think there is two ways: 1. Dynamic Action 2. Make own report template of type "Generic Columns (column template)" where you can refer to column values via #COLUMN_NAME#

Comment: I was looking into dynamic action, is it possible to use it within a report. I was messing around with it and can't find out how to include the columns of a report. (in affected elements dropdown). I wanted to be able to use it like how it functions with the items of the page. For your second point, I'm looking into it now, but do you mean a seperate report just for the columns I need to reference or all of the columns? Thanks. @NoGotnu

Answer (score 0):

1. Javascript/Dynamic Action:

   ```
   $('.dis_flag:contains(disabled="true")').parents('td[headers="DIS"]').siblings('td[headers="PHONE"]').children('input:text').attr('disabled', true);
   ```

where:

**DIS** - alias of my column, indicating disable editing or no (if disable it contains value **disabled="true"**. But it can have any another value).
**dis_flag** - class name, i added for this column in "Column Formatting" -> "CSS Class". I added this class to refer this value more easy.
**PHONE** - alias of column, that must be disabled.

You can add this javascript code to the

- "Page Load" Dynamic Action
- "Page Attributes" -> "JavaScript" ->    "Execute when Page Loads".

  2. Report template. Making your own report template is more difficult, and hard to explain in two words. Just go to the templates list, find report template named Two Column Portlet, type **Named Column (row template)** and maybe you will understand what i mean.

Comment: Formatting is so ugly on this site.